# Prove that $z_n \rightarrow z_0$ if and only if $\bar{z_n} \rightarrow \bar{z_0}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Tags: complex-analysis

In my Complex Analysis course, I'm supposed to prove that.  I'm not really too sure where to start, however.  Any pointers?

Thanks. :-)

Comment: Conjugation is continuous.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $|\bar{z_n} - \bar{z_0}| = |\overline{z_n - z_0}| = |z_n - z_0|$.

Comment: Hehe, thanks! More than a hint, even. ;-)

How are we sure that $|\bar{z_n} - \bar{z_0}| = |\overline{z_n - z_0}|$ though?

Comment: It's because $\bar{z_n} - \bar{z_0} = \overline{z_n - z_0}$.

Comment: @Lerbib I mean, you can write it out

$$\overline{x_1+x_2+i(y_2+y_2)}=x_1-iy_1+x_2-iy_2$$

Comment: Of course. Thanks @kobe.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon > 0$. {$z_n$} converges to $z_0$, so $\exists$ $k \in \Bbb N$ such that: $||z_n - z_0|| < \epsilon$, $\forall$ $n \ge k$.

Let $n \ge k$, we have:

$||z_n - z_0|| < \epsilon \Rightarrow ||\overline {z_n - z_0}|| < \epsilon \Rightarrow ||\overline{z_n} - \overline{z_0}|| < \epsilon$. The proof is complete in the first direction, I'll leave the second one for you.

Answer (score 1):

The map $z\to \bar{z}$ is continuous. So, if $\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n=z$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\overline{z_n}=\bar{z}$ by continuity.

You don't need to prove the converse, because $\bar{\bar{z}}=z$.

Why is $z\to\bar{z}$ continuous? Because $|z-w|=|\bar{z}-\bar{w}|$.